# add the option to enlarge screen in ant design charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, antd

Hi I am using ant desing charts [https://charts.ant.design/zh/examples/gallery](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
I would like to know if there is the option of full screen by graphic, or another way to do it
[https://charts.ant.design/en/docs/api/common-graph/common-graph](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I found this but I don't know if it's something that helps me or how to implement it, I'm new to using ant design chart, I already managed to paint the graphics but the next requirement is that I can make it full screen

As I said before, I tried these options [https://charts.ant.design/en/docs/api/common-graph/common-graph](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but nothing that can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the following example for its implementation

you can see script this link [script link](https://codesandbox.io/s/fullscreen-chart-5sqpc6?file=/src/App.js)

and demo this link [demo](https://5sqpc6.csb.app/)

Comment: The truth is that I had not found anything that would work for me, and this is an alternative, thank you very much.